# Add Variable in body of DBMail - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When adding a my variable @dateDifference to the message of the body, the body comes up blank on my Outlook. However, if I remove the variable, the message is printed in the email.

Below is my code:

```
DECLARE @sql                NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @dateDifference     NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @bodyMessage        NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = (SELECT backupFileDate 
                FROM #checkBackupTime 
                WHERE backupFileDate >= DATEADD(HH, -1, GETDATE()))

SET @dateDifference = (SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, @sql, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))

SET @bodyMessage = 'The lastest backup file is ' + @dateDifference + ' hours old'

IF @sql IS NULL OR @sql = '' 
    BEGIN

        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
            @recipients = 'my@email.com',
            @subject = N'mySubject',
            @body = @bodyMessage;
    END
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your choice of column names confuses me... why is the `BackupFileName` a `DATETIME`?  Why is the `BackupFileName` being set to a variable named `@sql`?  The nomenclature used here is perplexing...

Comment: If it really bothers you - I'll change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The naming convention used here is... confusing.  Nevertheless, there are several things wrong with your query:

1. The following code will break if there was more than one `backupFileName` within the previous hour.

---

```
SET @sql = (SELECT backupFileName
FROM #checkBackupTime 
WHERE backupFileName >= DATEADD(HH, -1, GETDATE()))
```

---

2. In the above code, you are only ever checking for `backupFileName`s in the past hour (more on that in #3).
3. The following code can only ever return one of three values:  `NULL`, `0`, or `1`.  The reason it can only ever be those three values is because you are *limiting* the results to just those files in the previous hour, and then asking how many hours old it is.  It will realistically only ever be `0` or `NULL` (in the case that there were no backups made in the last hour).

---

```
SET @dateDifference = (SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, @sql, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
```

---

4. The following code *should generate an error*.  You need to convert the `@dateDifference` to a `VARCHAR`:

---

```
SET @bodyMessage = 'The lastest backup file is ' + @dateDifference + ' hours old'
```

---

5. Because the value can only ever be `NULL` or `0`, `@bodyMessage` would end up being `NULL` if `@dateDifference` is `NULL`.  (a `VARCHAR` + `NULL` = `NULL`).
6. You are only ever sending the email if `@SQL IS NULL` or `''`!  You complain about your email coming out blank, *but you're only ever sending it if it is!*

---

```
IF @sql IS NULL OR @sql = '' 
BEGIN
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
    ...
```

---

**Proposed changes**

Remove the time constraint and grab the `MAX(backupFileName)`:

```
Select @Sql = Max(backupFileName)
From   #checkBackupTime
```

Use `COALESCE()` and `CONVERT()` for the value:

```
SET @bodyMessage = 'The lastest backup file is ' 
                       + Coalesce(Convert(Varchar, @dateDifference), '') 
                       + ' hours old'
```

And change the email condition to check the time since the last backup:

```
If @DateDifference > 1 
Begin
    Exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, made the suggested changes and everything seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

If `@datedifference` is `NULL` the whole expression is `NULL`. Try:

```
SET @bodyMessage = 'The lastest backup file is ' + ISNULL(@dateDifference, '') + ' hours old'
```